# Using BeautifulSoup to parse webpages – to skip 404 error pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using the code below to get the titles of websites.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

line_in_list = ['www.dailynews.lk','www.elpais.com','www.dailynews.co.zw']

for websites in line_in_list:
    url = "http://" + websites
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    site_title = soup.find_all("title")
    print site_title
```

If the list of websites contains a ‘bad’ (non-existent) website/webpage, or the website has some kind or error for example "404 page not found" etc., the script will break and stop.

In what way I can have the script to ignore/skip the ‘bad’ (non-existent) and problematic websites/webpages？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
line_in_list = ['www.dailynews.lk','www.elpais.com',"www.no.dede",'www.dailynews.co.zw']

for websites in line_in_list:
    url = "http://" + websites
    try:
       page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    site_title = soup.find_all("title")
    print(site_title)

[<title>Popular News Items | Daily News Online : Sri Lanka's National News</title>]
[<title>EL PAÍS: el periódico global</title>]
<urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
[<title>
DailyNews - Telling it like it is
</title>]
```